# How to echo user input and skip over punctuation and spaces? (Language C)

Tags: c, loops, echo

I've already got the part of my program that echoes user input to work, but my code seems to ignore the while line where I specify not to echo the characters in the array if they are spaces or punctuation. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int word = 0, punct = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char phrase[500];
    printf("Enter any phrase.");
    while (1)
    {
        do
        {
           phrase[i] = getchar(); //gets incoming char and outputs it
           putchar(phrase[i]);
        } while (phrase[i] != ' ' && phrase[i] != '.' && phrase[i] != '!' && phrase[i] != '@' && phrase[i] != '#' && phrase[i] != '$' && phrase[i] != '%' && phrase[i] != '%' && phrase[i] != '^' && phrase[i] != '&' && phrase[i] != '*' && phrase[i] != '(' && phrase[i] != ')' && phrase[i] != '-' && phrase[i] != '_' && phrase[i] != '=' && phrase[i] != '+' && phrase[i] != '\\' && phrase[i] != '|' && phrase[i] != '{' && phrase[i] != '}' && phrase[i] != '[' && phrase[i] != ']' && phrase[i] != ':' && phrase[i] != ';' && phrase[i] != '\'' && phrase[i] != '\"' && phrase[i] != '<' && phrase[i] != '>' && phrase[i] != ',' && phrase[i] != '?' && phrase[i] != '/'); //prevents punctuation and spaces from bein outputted
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

When I run the program the user input is all echoed, including the punctuation and spaces, what exactly is wrong and how do I make it so that the code outputs everything char by char and skip over the punctuation and spaces? And how would I keep the loop going after punctuation is skipped?

Comment: I think you want to use `|` (or) rather than `&&` (and) in your second while loop.

Comment: Properly indented code would make it easier to see your loop structure and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `//gets incoming char and outputs it`

This comment says it all. Your `do` loop outputs the character before the `while` test checks it. The `while` only stops when the input character is a punctuation mark, but by that time the character has already been sent. And then the outer `while (1)` loop causes the whole thing to happen all over again.

The way to fix the issue is to test the character *before* sending it to output. For example:

```
while(1) {
    phrase[i] = getchar();
    if (isPunctuation(phrase[i]) == false) {
        putchar(phrase[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't *really* want the `while (1)` since that means the loop will continue forever. After the 500th character, you'll exceed the capacity of the `phrase` array and start writing into memory that doesn't belong to you. I'll leave it to you to think up a more reasonable loop condition.

Comment: Ok im going to make these changes and try to alter the loop conditon, thanks a lot!